# Are there any JSF component libraries that generate semantic and cross-browser html markup?

Tags: jsf, semantic-markup

I'm using RichFaces per a client requirement, but the markup it (and the stock JSF controls) generates is an awful mess of nested tables.  Are there any control libraries out there that generate nicer markup?  AJAX support is a huge plus!

Comment: This question isn't about what 'semantic-web' usually means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is ICEFaces which provides more semantic support than RichFaces .Also you can try Nitobi suite which also provides similar kinda solution.If you are not satisfied with any of these I suggest try to write your own part extending the Sun faces

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No I have not yet found one.
Your options include using less complicated controls and know what html the standard controls emit. Thing like h:panelGrid render as a table. There is nothing stopping you writing your own rendering family which produces more standards compliment html, but this would be a big time investment. 
As for using RichFaces if you stick more to the a4j: namespace of tags you will still be getting the cross browser ajax with out all the mark up you don't like.

Comment: I've considered my own component set...I'm not a fan of a4j though as it seems to send a lot more data back and forth than is necessary.